Python CSV reader: need ignore quoted comma as delimiter
I need parse text file by comma, but not by quoted comma.
It looks like trivial task, but can't make Python do it right. Mainly because of an unquoted string prepending the quoted string, which makes it probably not well-formatted CSV, but I need it exactly this way.
Example input:
cmd,print "AA"
cmd, print "AA,BB,CC"
cmd,   print " AA, BB, CC ", separate-window

Desired result (in Python syntax):
[['cmd', 'print "AA"'], 
 ['cmd', 'print "AA,BB,CC"'], 
 ['cmd', 'print " AA, BB, CC "', 'separate-window']]

Stripping surrounding spaces is optional, once I get a proper list I can strip() each item, that's not a problem.
csv.reader splits by quoted commas too, so that I rather get ['cmd', 'print "AA', 'BB', 'CC"'].
shlex with altered .whitespace=',' and .whitespace_split=True almost does the trick, but removes quotes ['cmd', 'print AA, BB, CC']. I need retain quotes.
Thought about re.split but I have very weak understanding of how (?=) thingy works...
Found few similar topics over here, but none of the proposed answers work for me.
UPDATE: screenshot for whoever questioning if I do exactly what I describe:


csv.reader splits by quoted commas too It shouldn't.  Please show us the exact code you used, and an exact input file.

Exact input file I provided.
Exact code:
with open(test_list_name) as csvfile:
rtl_data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', skipinitialspace=True)
for padded_row in rtl_data:
row = tuple(cell.strip() for cell in padded_row)

Quotes have to be around the entire field. Quotes in the middle of a field have no special meaning.

@Jean-BaptisteYunès How will that help? There are no ' characters in the input file.

This is an invalid CSV file.

If you can't fix the input file, you'll need to write your own parser that checks for double quotes. I don't think you can do this with a regexp, they're terrible at distinguishing "inside quotes" from "outside quotes".

@Barmar yes I said in the question "this probably makes it not well-formatted CSV, but I need it exactly like this". Which makes me doubt that you tested my actual input example.

What do you mean? I deleted my comment saying I got the desired result because I looked again and saw it was wrong.

@barmar read too quickly...

@JohnGordon here is screenshot https://i.sstatic.net/nMMxT.png, clearly csv reader does NOT do what I need. I would love to see your screenshot confirming your words.

I misunderstood the output when I ran your code, and I deleted my earlier comment.  Barmar is right, that's an invalid csv file.  You can't have just part of a column enclosed in quotes, the whole column has to be in quotes.

@JohnGordon well before "Barmar was right", I wrote exactly the same in my question - this is not well-formed CSV. Luckily his comment about "inside quotes" gave me a clue what to google and I found solution.

After googling bit more and removing "python" from the query I found the solution. On some Java related topic was asked very similar question. And the answer was to use regex.
So I adjusted for Python and here exact code that works for me:
import re
splitter = re.compile(r',(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)')
with open('example.txt') as csvfile:
  for padded_row in csvfile:
    stripped_row = padded_row.rstrip()
    row = splitter.split(stripped_row)
    print(row)

Detailed explanation how it works
Thanks to commenters, you actually gave me some clues how to improve my googling queries :)

You'll probably need to handle this data yourself. I was able to produce your desired result with the following function:
def parse_line(line: str) -> list[str]:
  in_quote = False
  start = 0
  output = []
  stripped_line = line.strip()
  for index, char in enumerate(stripped_line):
    if char == '"':
      in_quote = not in_quote
    if char == ',' and not in_quote:
      output.append(stripped_line[start:index])
      start = index + 1
  else:
    if index + 1 != start:
      output.append(stripped_line[start:len(stripped_line)])
  return output

for line in csvfile:
  print(parse_line(line))

['cmd', 'print "AA"']
['cmd', ' print "AA,BB,CC"']
['cmd', '   print " AA, BB, CC "', ' separate-window']


Writing own parser is always obvious option, but I didn't want to invent wheel if it is already invented.
